# Crystal Reports to SSRS conversion

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a situation where I am converting Crystal Reports to SSRS.

The difficulty I am encountering is that Crystal Reports are more "free form", for lack of a better phrase.  The reports i am converting have numerous groupings (eight in all) and are put out in more of a haphazard free form way, in both the grouping headers/footers and in the detail band, and I am trying to convert that layout to SSRS.

SSRS is more "rigid", if you well, with the Table layout cells for the detail band, and makes the free form layout more difficult, i.e. placing fields out in a free form manner as opposed to being relegated to the rigid table grid format of SSRS.

I suppose I could create a separate Dataset with the same Stored procedure input to produce the desired result, but wow that's a lot of extra processing.

Any ideas or suggestions?  Hope my question makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you need more of a Form look, try using a Text Box inside of a List.  You can associate the List to a Dataset and then assign the Text Box to a field from the dataset.  The List can encompass the whole body and the Text Box can be anywhere within the List.  If the List set to the size of the Body, each record in your dataset will populate the text boxes on a new "page".

Also make sure you understand the difference between the Body object and the Page object.  body size + page margins = page size.